# installed MinCW & cygwin but can't compile anything

Tags: c, compilation, mingw

Everytime I try and compile a simple hello world program I get a console full of errors. I have DevC++ and when I use the IDE it compiles fine and works great but I start doing everything from Notepad++ and the command line. Here's my error:

```
C:\Users\root\Desktop>g++ helloworld.c -o helloworld.exe
In file included from c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/
4.4.3/../../../../include/stdio.h:26,
                from helloworld.c:1:
c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../i686
-w64-mingw32/include/stddef.h:20: error: expected constructor, destruc
tor, or type conversion before '_set_errno'
c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../i686
-w64-mingw32/include/stddef.h:21: error: expected constructor, destruc
tor, or type conversion before '_get_errno'
c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../i686
-w64-mingw32/include/stddef.h:26: error: expected initializer before '
__threadhandle'
In file included from helloworld.c:1:
c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../incl
ude/stdio.h:191: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../incl
ude/stdio.h:202: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../incl
ude/stdio.h:206: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../incl
ude/stdio.h:209: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../incl
ude/stdio.h:210: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../incl
ude/stdio.h:289: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conv
ersion before 'fread'
c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../incl
ude/stdio.h:290: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conv
ersion before 'fwrite'
In file included from helloworld.c:1:
c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../incl
ude/stdio.h:438: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../incl
ude/stdio.h:442: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../incl
ude/stdio.h:446: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conv
ersion before 'fgetwc'
c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../incl
ude/stdio.h:447: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conv
ersion before 'fputwc'
c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../incl
ude/stdio.h:448: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conv
ersion before 'ungetwc'
c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../incl
ude/stdio.h:453: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conv
ersion before 'getwc'
c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../incl
ude/stdio.h:454: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conv
ersion before 'getwchar'
c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../incl
ude/stdio.h:456: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conv
ersion before 'putwc'
c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../incl
ude/stdio.h:458: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conv
ersion before 'putwchar'
c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../incl
ude/stdio.h:472: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../incl
ude/stdio.h:474: error: 'size_t' has not been declared
c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../incl
ude/stdio.h:496: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conv
ersion before '_fgetwchar'
c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../incl
ude/stdio.h:497: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conv
ersion before '_fputwchar'
c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../incl
ude/stdio.h:502: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conv
ersion before 'fgetwchar'
c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../incl
ude/stdio.h:503: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conv
ersion before 'fputwchar'
```

Comment: It looks as if stddef.h are not parsed correctly. size_t is not known, and that leads to all kinds of follow-up errors. Perhaps there is an environment variable set by DEVC++ which affects gcc? Cf. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html, or on the contrary there's one missing which must be there for mingw's gcc.

Comment: thanks, i got it to work, i uninstalled devC++ and then reinstalled mincw devc++ must have been conflictering with something

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you use wrong library (maybe the file is damaged or doesn’t exist in the location searched by the compiler). Or maybe you haven’t added all libraries you needed to. I’ve had the same problem when I typed the library name incorrectly.